# distance between multilinestring and point

Tags: java, gis, geotools

If I have to calculate the nearest distance between a point and a polygon (point and lake (naturalearthdata.com) for example), I can do (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045598/java-geotools-how-to-find-distance-from-a-point-to-closest-polygon-in-shape-fil)):

```
...
LocationIndexedLine line = new LocationIndexedLine(((MultiPolygon)    feature.getDefaultGeometry()).getBoundary());
LinearLocation here = line.project(coordinate);
Coordinate point = line.extractPoint(here);
...
```

and :

```
      ...
      NearestPolygon polyFinder = new NearestPolygon(features);

      GeometryFactory gf = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();
      Point p = gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(-49.2462798, -16.7723987));

      Point pointOnLine = polyFinder.findNearestPolygon(p);
      if (!pointOnLine.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(pointOnLine + " is closest to " + p);
        SimpleFeature lastMatched2 = polyFinder.getLastMatched();
        String attribute = (String) lastMatched2.getAttribute("name");
        if(attribute.isEmpty()) {
          attribute = (String) lastMatched2.getAttribute("note");
        }
        if (((Geometry) (lastMatched2.getDefaultGeometry())).contains(p)) {
          System.out.println("is in lake " + attribute);
        } else {
          System.out.println("nearest lake is " + attribute);
        }
...
```

Until here ok.

But, how can I find the closest distance between a point and a coastline which is a multilinestring and not a polygon.
Or, if I have a linestring?

What approach should I follow?What about `LocationIndexedLine` and `LinearLocation`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve this by changing the line to:

```
LocationIndexedLine line = new LocationIndexedLine(((Geometry)
     feature.getDefaultGeometry()));
```

For some reason getDefaultGeometry returns an `Object` so you need to cast it to something useful.

Comment: Hmm.Nice!It works!But what about (I just noticed) if I have a "Point" geometry?If I use the above it shows me `Input geometry must be linear`.If I use the original `new LocationIndexedLine(((MultiPolygon) feature.getDefaultGeometry()).getBoundary());` it shows `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point cannot be cast to com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.MultiPolygon` and if I replace `MultiPolygon` with `Point` in the previous line, it shows again `Input geometry must be linear`.And what if I have a `Multipoint`?Thank you very much!(upvoted)

Comment: The indexed lines are to work out the point on the line or boundary that is closest to your point, if you have two points then you can simply calculate the distance between the two, for a multipoint calculate the distance to each one and pick the closest

Comment: I just use "ports.shp"  instead of "lakes.shp" as you have [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045598/java-geotools-how-to-find-distance-from-a-point-to-closest-polygon-in-shape-fil).And it shows that it is a geom.Point.So, you say in that case not to use any LocationIndexedLine but just calculate distance?Thanks!

Comment: The indexed lines are to work out the point on the line or boundary that is closest to your point, if you have two points then you can simply calculate the distance between the two, for a multipoint calculate the distance to each one and pick the closest

Comment: Ok, thanks! ( I opened a new [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45189672/read-coordinates-from-shp-file-and-compute-distance?noredirect=1#comment77369121_45189672)) for this.I am having difficulty to read the coordinates from the ports.shp file.In the polygon case we use `BBOX`, 'ReferencedEnvelope`, `LocationIndexedLine`, but in this case, I am lost!

Comment: Can I ask you about bathymetry, since you seem to know these things well?I want to calculate the depth at some point.But I see that bathymetry files from natural earth data are "bathymetry 2000, 5000, 7000..".So, how is it possible to compute a depth in a point?Thank you very much!